# preprocessing EEG dataset in python to get better accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've an EEG dataset which has 8 features taken using 8-channel EEG headset. Each row represents readings taken with 250ms interval. The values are all floating point representing voltages in micro volt. If I plot individual features, I can see that they form a continuous wave. now the target has 3 categories: 0,1,2.  and for a duration of time the target doesn't change because the sample taken spans across multiple rows. I would appreciate any guidance as to how to pre-process the dataset. Since using it as it is gives me very low accuracy(80%) and according to Wikipedia P300 signal can be detected with 95% accuracy. And please note that I've almost zero knowledge about signal processing and analysing waveforms.

I did try making a 3D array where each row represented a single target and the values of each feature was a list of values that originally spanned across multiple rows. But I get an error that says estimator array expected to be <=2. I'm not sure if this was the right approach. But it didn't work anyway.

here have a look at my **feature set**:-

```
-1.2198,-0.32769,-1.22,2.4115,0.057031,-2.6568,7.372,-0.2789 
-1.4262,-4.19,-5.6546,-7.7161,-5.4359,-9.4553,-3.6705,-5.4851
-1.3152,-6.8708,-8.5599,-14.739,-9.1808,-14.268,-11.632,-8.929
-0.53987,-7.5156,-8.9646,-16.656,-10.119,-15.791,-14.616,-9.4095
```

Their corresponding **targets**:-

```
0 
0 
0 
0
```